# Installing Xubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows XP stops copying files at ~60% despite plenty of space on the HD

Tags: boot, system-installation, xubuntu

I chose to install Xubuntu with Windows, using [this link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows). My operating system is Windows XP Professional 32-bit. Everything worked fine during installation until the file copying step. It stopped after copying about 60% in the boot section. The hard drive space is not a problem, as it has still plenty of disk space left.

Has anybody experienced a similar problem? If I copy this Xubuntu 12.04 via a bootable USB-stick and install it in a separate partition, would this work, or would it be better to get another download?

Comment: Create a bootable USB, and install along side windows.  See [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support)

Answer (score 1):

Check for the corruption of downloaded Ubuntu Installation Media (iso file).
Verify the md5sum of the xubuntu 12.04 iso file with the checksum given on the website (from where you have downloaded the iso.
You can use this utility(for windows)
[www.winmd5.com/‎](http://www.winmd5.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use USB (which I recomend) then take this tool: [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). It is known application for making bootable flash drives. All instructions can be found on their site. Also make sure to download Ubuntu from torrents, in my experience you'll get .iso image with less corrumptions.